# jQuery div's height changes

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, equals

Consider the following html layout:

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="sidebar-left"></div>
  <div class="main-content">
    <div class="main-content-inner"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

`.main-content` and `.sidebar-left` are getting an inline height, set by an equalheights function using javascript/jQuery

The content in `.main-content` is dynamic, so it changes (ajax, upload-fields,...). 
The equalheights function should be re-applied on both elements when the height of `.main-content-inner` is no longer equal to `.main-content`

How can I do this with javascript/jQuery?

Comment: Have you even tried any JS of your own?

Comment: You can trigger a function call into the `success` function of the ajax call.... You will find a lot of example by googling a little!

Comment: @JoDev not every height change is invoked by ajax, so I can't use that.

Comment: But you can make a function called each time the `#main-content` change!!

Comment: @JamieHutber I have tried re-applying the equalheights function whenever $(window).resize(); is triggerd, but the resizing of my div doesn't activate window.resize.

Comment: add that code to the question then, then we might be able to see what the hell you're actually doing.

Comment: @1ntello .resize(); can only be used on $(window)

Comment: @JrnDel use this then: http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-resize-plugin/

Comment: @1ntello Thanks for the plugin, it does exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about adding an event on the resize of the div with the following plugin:

So like `$(window).resize()` but then for the div

[benalman.com/projects/jquery-resize-plugin](http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-resize-plugin)

Comment: I would recommend you to do it only when resize is finished: http://alvarotrigo.com/blog/firing-resize-event-only-once-when-resizing-is-finished/

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to script to sync height. Just use some new selector in css as below:

**CSS:**

```
.wrapper {
  position:relative;
}
.sidebar-left {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 330px; /* Example */
  padding: 15px; /* Example */
}
.main-content {
  margin-left: 350px;
  width: 100%;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="sidebar-left"></div>
  <div class="main-content">
    <div class="main-content-inner"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```